# BufferedReader stops reading large Json from HttpURLConnection without error

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader, httpconnection

I am trying to get the data of some images in Base64 with a REST request from an android application.

The while bucle seems to work for a few iterations and then stops reading with no exception and no information in the android log.

I tried several examples and none worked for me as you can see in the commented code.

I can get the full response from the server using a REST plugin for chrome. So the REST service is not the problem.

In debug mode, i can see how response is reading fine for some iterations, but eventually, when the execution reaches the read method, it simply stops with no information at all.

The total response string i see with the chrome plugin is aprox 150k characters length. And with the java code i can't read even 10k.

```
public static String getRestResult(
        String method,
        String table,
        String filter,
        String input) throws IOException {

    if (filter==null) filter = "";
    String urlFinal = restServiceHost+":"+restServicePort+"/"+table+filter;
    System.out.println("urlFinal="+urlFinal);
    URL url = new URL(urlFinal);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setConnectTimeout(1500000);
    conn.setReadTimeout(1500000);
    String result = "";

    if (method!=null) {

        if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("GET")) {

            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        } else if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Prefer", "return=representation");

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(input.getBytes());
            os.flush();

        } else {
            throw new IOException("Method not supported.");
        }
        System.out.println("conn.getResponseCode()="+conn.getResponseCode());
        if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200 || conn.getResponseCode() == 201) {

                InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] byteChunk = new byte[4096];
                int n;
                while ( (n = is.read(byteChunk)) > 0 ) {
                    baos.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
                }

                result = baos.toString();



                //-----------------------------------------------------------

                //result = IOUtils.toString(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

                //_------------------------------------------------



            }catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

                if (conn!=null) conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

    } else {
        throw new IOException("Method must be indicated.");
    }

    return result;
}
```

If i print in each iteration the bytes readed and the acumulated, this is what i get:

...
Readed 2048 (9729 total)
Readed 648 (10377 total)
Readed 2048 (12425 total)
Readed 640 (13065 total)
Readed 1794 (14859 total)

But it's more content in the response.
read method never returns -1.
Everything simply stops silently.

I don't understand why is reading 2048 max at a time if i defined a 4096 buffer.

Comment: You do need to close the input stream. Try a read timeout. Dnt post commented-out code, and don't leave it lying around either. Either it works or it doesn't. Nothing in between.

Comment: Sorry for the commented code. Yes , the input stream has to be closed. I already set a read timeout for the connection if that's what you mean.

Comment: So therefore either you read to end of stream or you got a read timeout. Which is it?

Comment: A read timeout would throw an exception, and if the end of stream is reached, next iteration of read method returns -1 and exits the loop. None of them is the case.

Comment: So to be clear you are just blocking in read for more than 150s?

Comment: The 150s timeout is just one of the solutions i tried. Anyway the read function stops much befora than that. I think the problem may be that my code cannot read all the chunks of the response. Just read the first of it.